# Nativescript - error on tns run android

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to run android emulator with the command `tns run android`. This starts the emulator but it keeps stuck on Android logo and I get the following error:

> (...)
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 17.013 secs
>   Project successfully built.
>   Using  C:\(...)\sample-Groceries\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\sampleGroceries-debug.apk
>   Starting Android emulator with image Nexus6
>   Waiting for emulator device initialization..............
>
> Cannot run your app in the native emulator. Increase the timeout of the operation with the --timeout option or try to restart your adb
>   server with 'adb kill-server' command. Alternatively, run the Android
>   Virtual Device manager and increase the allocated RAM for the virtual
>   device.
>   (...)

Here is my Android Virtual Device configured:

**AVD Manager**

[image]

Note: I can run the application on my phone anyway, but not on my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

In Android Virtual Device Manager, there was an error I didn't see:

[AVD Manager error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9OAT.jpg)

Comment: I got the same problem lastweek and I got it fixed by downloading the latest emulator.  ^ ^.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which I found to be useful.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwkOo.png)

You just have to manually activate the emulator, which you can do using android studio or command line. Using the command line, you have to run this command

```
emulator -avd avd_name [ {-option [value]} … ]
```

for ex:

```
/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd test
```

Once the emulator starts you can run this command

```
tns run android
```

Answer (score 0):

I started having similar issue after updating to the latest Android Studio and latest emulators. I switched the VM Heap to 64, and it worked for me. May be worth giving that a try.

Answer (score 0):

> Open your Android Virtual Device Manager and download the latest
>   emulator. That will fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed that by:

1. Open emulator manually from Android Studio (double-click on position in AVD Manager list)
2. Run `tns run android`

Works for macOS Sierra.